# How to use ACL or PAC while using OpenVPN?

Tags: dns, openvpn

Currently I use a ip table to divide traffic when using OpenVPN, achieving this by running a script to `sudo route add` a list of IPs I like to connect directly.

This posts an issue. When I request a url, it still would run via OpenVPN's DNS, and return an IP that might not be usable if I connect it directly (I am in China, GFW blocks Facebook, Google, and a lot of foreign IPs/domains, so I can't use local DNS either).

Ideally, I would have ACL or PAC where it does a local DN first and figure out which DNS (local or international) to use and connect according. How would this be done under Linux or Unix?

Answer (score 1):

First, when doing routing, it's usually not necessary to also use `iptables`, unless you want to do something complicated for some reason.

You didn't say if you are splitting the traffic based on a list of complete addresses, or if you are splitting by prefixes etc. So please edit your question and provide this information.

If you split based on complete addresses, the simplest solution is to just add names for those addresses to `/etc/hosts`. Lookup in this file takes precedence over DNS lookup (unless configured otherwise in `nssswitch.conf`). Of course, both the IP addresses in this file and in your routing file need to be updated if changed.

Another option is to use `/etc/resolv.conf`. From `man 5 resovler`:

> `nameserver Name server IP address`
>
> Internet address of a  name  server  that  the  resolver  should
>   query [...] Up  to  MAXNS  (currently 3, see ) name servers may be
>   listed, one per keyword.  If there  are  multiple  servers,  the
>   resolver  library queries them in the order listed.

However, this file is usually automatically generated by various other parts of the system, and the details differ from Linux distribution to Linux distribution. So you must find out which scripts are executed for your DHCP client and/or OpenVPN to update this file with the received nameserver information, and then modify those scripts so both `nameserver` entries end up in `resolv.conf` in the correct order.

In this form, it will only work if the Chinese DNS server fails to return an IP address for blocked domains. If the Chinese DNS server behaves differently, e.g. if you have to test the IP returned to find out if it's blocked or not, or if you need different kind of tests, it will even get more difficult: You'll have to use some kind of local DNS proxy that does those tests, and probably modify the code of an existing proxy software.

I would assume other people in China who have used VPNs already have run into the same problem, so possibly there's also some ready-made solution out there, but the international community likely doesn't know about those.

Comment: Adding names to `/etc/hosts` does not override the behavior of the traffic - it still goes through VPN.

Comment: Using a VPN essentially makes my traffic none-Chinese, which means the DNS will return IPs of Chinese domains outside of China (if they have servers abroad) - which means slow/unusable network - and sometimes Chinese domains's foreign servers don't provide similar services (for example most of the real time database providers), resulting at call chain failure...

Comment: Of course you need proper `ip route` rules, so Chinese IPs (prefixes) don't go through the VPN, while the rest does. That's a different problem, I thought your main problem was IP lookup (DNS service): Return either the Chinese or non-Chinese IP based on your preference.

Comment: thats very primative and stated in the question that i am doing this. it also doesnt do domain recognition like pac does. so it must go through the dns which leads to the same problem described about.

Comment: If you only want this for HTTP traffic (and you didn't say so in the question), then yes, a proxy would be a solution. See e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1185861/linux-routing-based-on-domain-names/1186285). (Though that still doesn't explain why `/etc/hosts` doesn't work for you ...).

Comment: no. but it would be nice to have .pac effect on http and https traffic. still doesnt know what hosts has to do with any of this. oh u mean adding all chinese sites with ip addresses? it would create a huge hosts file and exceed thr size limit.